# PostMapping annotation causes a whitelabel error page in SpringBoot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, maven

I'm new to Java and react web development and I'm having an issue with my postBody method. After sending a post request, the console prints the data posted from my frontend correctly, but it shows a whitelabel error page that says (type=Not Found, status=404) in localhost:8080/api and (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405) in localhost:8080/api/data. Below is the HelloController code.

```
package com.java.java.practice;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HelloController {
//this performes a post and get request
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000/api")
@PostMapping(value="/n", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String postBody(@RequestBody String fullName) {
        System.out.println(fullName);
        return "Hello " + fullName; //returns response
    }

}
```

Below is the main application

```
package com.java.java.practice;



import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.java.java.practice")
public class PracticeApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PracticeApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

The weird thing is, when I replace my HelloController code with the one posted underneath, the whitelabel page goes away and shows text on the screen.

```
package com.java.java.practice;



import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;


@RestController
public class HelloController {
//this performes a post and get request
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000/api")
@RequestMapping("/api")
    public String postBody() {
        return "Hello"; //returns response
    }

 }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few issues as below,

1. When you try to call via a web browser it's always calling as HTTP GET. But in your RestController, there is no GET method. It only has a POST method. Try to use Postman or CURL to call post method instead of GET.
2. Your URL is wrong. Since you appending `/n` for the PostMapping annotation it should be (`http://localhost:3000/api/n`)
3. Only you want fullName as request body try to use PathVariable instead. No point to use RequestBody only for 1 parameter. Sample code as below.

   ```
    @PostMapping(value="/{fullName}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String postBody(@PathVariable String fullName) {
        System.out.println(fullName);
        return "Hello " + fullName; //returns response
    }
   ```